# Top-level staging-site URL redirects to a different site

Tags: redirect, subdomains, staging

I have a site, let's call it resources.mycompany.ca - and I just set up staging for it at resources-staging.mycompany.ca .

The staging site works fine if I try to visit any specific URL (i.e. resources-staging.mycompany.ca/something). But if I try to visit the top-level URL, resources-staging.mycompany.ca/ , I'm taken to the homepage of a completely different site-in-progress, staging.mycompany.ca .

I've checked the "Site Address" and "WordPress Address" settings and they're correct, they both say "resources-staging.company.ca". I've looked at .htaccess, nothing funny there. I've checked Permalinks and re-saved. There's no redirects of any sort set up anywhere.

My only thought is that my use of "staging" preceded by a dash violated some WordPress or hosting rule... or caused it to be interpreted as just "staging", not "resources-staging" (which is essentially what's happening!). But to test this would be non-trivial (setting up a different subdomain, which is done by our IT company) so I thought I'd ask here first.

Thanks to anyone who can suggest anything!

Comment: Check your `wp-config.php` file for [`WP_SITEURL`](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#wp-siteurl) and/or [`WP_HOME`](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#blog-address-url) being defined; these will override the content of your database if they're present.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Pat J! But alas, there's no reference to either of those in the config file. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, like many things it was just a matter of playing the waiting game. The main URL now works fine. Just needed to wait a few days, I guess!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).